# Error while fetching data from cross domain using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json

When i try to fetch the data using JSON from cross domain, i am getting this kind of error  `"Error: jQuery1910031708905171111246_1388038501367 was not called"`

I am using ajax callback functionality and my jQuery  version is 1.9.1.

```
$.ajax({  
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'my url',                  //the script to call to get data         
                    jsonp: "callback",
                    dataType: 'jsonp', //data format 
                    timeout: 10000,
                    success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
                    {
                                var id = data[0];              //get id
                                var vname = data[1];           //get name

                         $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname);     //Set output element html
                    },
                    error: function (request, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Does the URL you are using support JSONP?

Comment: I am getting response(Using firebug) but It goes in error function not in success function. I have changed page content to Application/JSON for my php page.

Comment: Please show the response - I don't think you are returning JSONP format. If you are using JSONP you should not set the page content to application/json because what you'd actually be returning would be JavaScript.

Comment: here i send u link of page i create http://viciproperties.com/wp-content/themes/viciproperties/api.php

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/03424zbacd this is link where i got the response which is shows in firebug

Comment: That link is returning JSON, not JSONP. To use JSONP it needs to return `callback([{"listing_id":"6", etc...}]);`

Comment: Thank you very much i got solution from your answer